# wxpython RichtextCtrl event bindings on buttons/images

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxtextctrl, wx.textctrl

Just wondering whether there is any provision/method to bind clicks on images/(or include a button) to result into some events. Also is there any kind of way to draw a StaticLine kind of thing in a RichTextCtrl in wxPython.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...  You can bind to clicking on a button (it wouldn't be a great button otherwise).  Do you want to draw a graphical line inside a RichTextCtrl programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to a button if you like, you could use a bitmapbutton instead, or bind mouse events to your static bitmap. The wxPython demo has examples for all of these methods.

With regards to the "StaticLine kinda thing", are you trying to resize the richtextctrl on demand? You might want to look at the ExpandoTextCtrl instead, which is also demonstrated in the demo. If not, I would need some more detail than "kinda thing".. ;)